# CTRL + ALT combination not captured by teamviewer in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys, remote-access, teamviewer

I am using TeamViewer 12 from Ubuntu 16.04 to access a remote computer with Ubuntu 16.04. I would like to go start TTY mode in the remote computer, however when I type CTRL + ALT + F1, the command is captured by my local Ubuntu and I am not able to send the signal to the remote computer.

I have already seen that there are a lot of questions concerning this problem, however I was not able to find a question regarding my local and remote OS versions.

Comment: Probably because it still uses wine (in some sort of way). It's not actually running in wine, but it's not truly native either. I've had this issue and due to lack of time, switched to a Windows machine. Not being able to send Ctrl+Alt+Del is really annoying if you have to unlock a remote Windows machine.

Comment: Yeah, I can confirm it still relies on Wine (version 1.6). Unfortunately, switching to Windows is not one of my possible choices